# How to do cross validation if dataset is partitioned to training and testing sets?

Tags: classification, cross-validation

I am doing Microarray dataset analysis of Leukemia Cancer dataset.
The dataset has following details

Training :- 38 Samples, 7130 Attributes. 
Testing :- 34 Samples, 7130 Attributes.

Dataset is real valued with two classes(Binary dataset).

Here, dimension of the dataset is too huge compared to no of sample. So I did Principal Component Analysis (PCA). In order to do PCA, I combined Training and Testing Dataset to single file (now total 72 instances) and applied PCA. I selected 72 principal components (PCs) as they provided cumulative variance of 1.

Now I have reduced dataset of dimension 72 x 72. So can I use this dataset  on SVM classifier and apply 10 cross validation ? is it right approach ?

Comment: That's too few samples for so many attributes, let alone cross validation. With this data I am afraid you cannot generate anything but a hallucinating model.

Comment: You will typically perform cross-validation on the training sample only. You might want to look at regularization techniques, like the logistic lasso or elastic net. (@CagdasOzgenc: +1 for the "hallucinating model"!)

Comment: I am not sure anything will work here. What people don't realize is that PCA overfits as well. Basically your dimensionality reduction may fail on the test set. When you have so many attributes the chances of finding rabbits in the clouds becomes extremely high. The saturation of total variation is actually a confirmation of overfit. Can you somehow generate more data?

Comment: Do not apply PCA to the whole dataset and then partition into training and testing subsets. If you do that, you will have used the testing data in the model building phase, which will lead to over-optimistic, biased results. Don't use the test data for anything but testing! That said, I don't see what makes this particular test set special. You could easily do cross-validation on the full 72 sample dataset - just don't use all 72 to find the principal components.

Comment: How was decided which case becomes training and which case becomes test case?

Answer (score 1):

> I selected 72 principal components

Note: There was no selection here: 72 PCs cover your complete data set as having 72 rows implies that the rank cannot be more than 72.

So your PCA is only a pure rotation of the data, and in that sense didn't change anything but the number of columns of the data matrix. But if your microarray data happens to be of a type where you expect only few variates to carry information at all, PCA is probably not the best preprocessing technique. (PCA is great if you have data where the information is spread out over *many* channels).

You may find the chapter about regularization in the Elements of Statistical Learning helpful.

> can I use this dataset on SVM classifier and apply 10 cross validation ? is it right approach ?

Contrary to the other answer, I'd say cross validation *for testing* is your best chance here unless the test set was collected as a separate experiment set up explicitly (and professionally!) to serve as a test set.

Single split into train and test is highly inefficient in terms of making use of the few cases you have. Assuming that you'll report results as sensitivity and specificity and you have 17 positive cases and 17 controls in your test set, your point estimates and 95% confidence intervals for the possible outcomes of the testing are:

[image: binomial 95% confidence intervals for 17 tested cases]

Now the question for you is: if the outcome were 2 misclassified cases, i.e. a 95 % confidence interval for sensitivy ranging from 68% to 98% be of any use judging whether the model works or whether this is a promising technique?
(Cross validation for validation using the whole data set may not be that much better, but at least you'd then have done what is possible with that data set)

Within the training set using an inner cross validation for tuning of the SVM parameters, you pretty much have the same problem: the confidence interval widths I depicted above give the uncertainty due to having only few test cases. Data driven optimization of the model, i.e. multiple comparisons of models trained with varying hyperparameters will most likely give just spurious results (the hallucinating model) where in fact you choose a model for which the cross validation splitting was lucky.

=> Conclusion: either fix the hyperparameters yourself (e.g. based on previous experience with similar data) or go for a model that doesn't need hyperparameter tuning. With original 7000 variates and just 70 cases, you don't want to look for for particularly fancy models (and for sure not for nonlinear models), you look for very stable (aggregated or highly regularized) models. Models like random forest without tuning (but possibly considering only very few of the original data), or L0 regularization looking for the 3 best variates if you happen to think from literature that you'd expect 3 features to carry information.

Answer (score 0):

You can try LOOCV on the training set using a logistic regression model with an l1 penalty, or an SVM with an l1 penalty. Because you have N < P, where N denotes the sample size and P the amount of variables (columns), any non regularized model will most likely be "ill defined". That's where the l1 penalty comes in as it will "choose" features for you and simulatenously give you classification metrics (accuracy, AUC, F1 score - you have to decided which you want, however ROC-AUC is considered as a sort of "gold standard"), where in the final model only the chosen features contributed to the classification results.

What I might do is LOOCV (leave one out cross validation) on your training set only and then use the testing set in a predictive context, to assess the model you created in the cross validation phase.

scikit-learn has readily available tools for what I just described.

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegressionCV.html for the model, you can set it to use "l1" as the penalty

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score.html for the classification metric

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.LeaveOneOut.html  for the cross validation.

Here's a possible set up:

```
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import LeaveOneOut
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score

loocv = LeaveOneOut()
clf = Pipeline([
    ('scale', StandardScaler()),
    ('logistic_regression', linear_model.LogisticRegressionCV(
         penalty = 'l1',
         solver = 'liblinear',
         cv = loocv)
    )])

clf.fit(training_data, training_response)
prediction = clf.predict(testing_dat)
roc_auc = roc_auc_score(testing_response, prediction)
```

In addition you can get information on which features were included in the model from :

```
columns = clf.named_steps['logistic_regression'].coef_
columns_chosen = zip(data_columns, columns)
```

and look at the nonzero pairs.

Another possible approach is to combine all of your data and use LOOCV.

Another line of attack could be using extra trees and or random forest. You could generate a variable of random data that you know has nothing to do with your response variable. Include that in your model and look at the feature importance rankings from the random forest fitting within your training data only. Discard any features whose importance was less than or equal to that of the random column. Use the selected features to predict on your testing set.